# What does it mean when we put a variable inside { } in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, syntax, variable-assignment, curly-braces

I am interested to know what kind of difference does it make when we put the left side variable of an assignment statement into a `{}`?

For example:

```
import {....} from ,,,,
```

VS

```
  import .... from ,,,,
```

Also

```
const {....} = function(,,,,)
```

VS

```
const .... = function(,,,,)
```

Comment: It is called destructuring, and it is a javascript syntax!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: In case of imports, the ones with braces are called "named imports", and the ones without braces are called "default imports".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import